# Mi peticion de AJAX JQuery no se procesa

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, bootstrap

Estoy desarrollando un sitio de un servicio medico con PHP5,Ajax y MySQL, en la seccion de pacientes, el usuario puede visualizar a los registrados actualmente. Sin embargo, en caso de que no se encuentre, hay un boton que despliega un modal de Boostrap con un formulario. El punto es que el usuario llene dicho formulario y puede agregar a un nuevo paciente sin tener que recargar la pagina, mediante ajax.

eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
eeeeeeeeeeeeee
eeeeeeeeeeeeee

Codigo Seccion Pacientes

```
<head>
        <script>    
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "InsertarPaciente.php", success: function(res)}){
                $("#div1").html(res);

               }
          });
          });
         </script>    
         </head>
         <body>

          <!--Banner Superior-->
          <?php
        session_start();
        $varsession = $_SESSION['usuario'];

         <!--Modal Formulario-->      
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 test" style="overflow-y:scroll">  
         <br>
         <center><h2>Pacientes</h2></center>
         <br>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-mod1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Registrar    Paciente</button>


          <div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-            labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-  label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <center><h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Registrar    Nuevo Paciente</h4></center>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
       <form  method="post" class="form-mod" id="agregarpaciente">
       <br>
        <div class="area">    
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nombre(s)</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control inputs">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Apellido Paterno</label>
        <input type="text" name="ap_paterno" class="form-control inputs">
        </div>    

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Apellido Materno</label>
        <input type="text" name="ap_materno" class="form-control inputs">
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Edad</label>
        <input type="text" name="edad" class="form-control inputs">
        </div> 

         <div class="form-group">
         <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Staff</label>
         <input type="text" name="staff" class="form-control inputs">
         </div>   

         <div class="form-group">
         <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Procedencia</label>
         <br><select id="ini4" name="proced">
         <option value="Externo">Externo</option>
         <option value="Interno">Interno</option>
         </select>
         </div>     

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Alergias</label>
        <br><textarea rows="4" cols="30" class="txt1" name="alergias">
        </textarea>
        </div> 

          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">
           </div></form>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-  dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>

          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <!--Buscador-->
        <form class="form4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Busqueda</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control in1" id="exampleInputEmail1"      placeholder="Ingrese nombre o numero de staff">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btnpac">Buscar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btnpac2">Borrar</button>
        </form>     

        </div>


            </div>

           <div id="div1">   </div>

         </div>



        </body>
        </html>
```

My php es:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Registro Agregado</title>
    <link href="med.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

<body id="body">    

<?php


include 'ConexionBD.php';


$nm = utf8_decode($_POST['nombre']);
$ap = utf8_decode($_POST['ap_paterno']);
$am = utf8_decode($_POST['ap_materno']);
$ed = utf8_decode($_POST['edad']);
$st = utf8_decode($_POST['staff']);
$pr = utf8_decode($_POST['proced']);
$al = utf8_decode($_POST['alergias']);



$sql = "INSERT INTO pacientes (nombre,ap_paterno,ap_materno,edad,staff,procedencia,alergias)values('$nm','$ap','$am','$ed','$st',
'$pr','$al')";

$op = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

if($op){

    echo "Agregado Correctamente";

}else{

    echo "error al agregar";
}


$link->close();

?>



</body>
</html>
```

El problema es que cuando le doy al boton de:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">
```

no hace nada.

Comment: Tienes el código JS al inicio del documento HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está incompleto y mal.

No estás previniendo el submit del formulario tras el click en javascript, por lo que intenta hacer submit mediante HTML no mediante AJAX. En la llamada AJAX no estás pasándole el formulario, por lo que no estás enviando nada a PHP. Tampoco estás indicando el tipo de petición que envías. Por otro lado, el código javascript va siempre antes de terminar la etiqueta `body` para optimizar el renderizado de la página y no bloquee la carga de los elementos visuales al usuario.

Te recomiendo que captures el evento del submit del formulario para que no entre en conflicto con el envío de éste mediante HTML y no AJAX. Además puedes capturar su contenido fácilmente con `serialize()`. Tu código quedaría así:

```
<head></head>

<body>
   <!--Banner Superior-->
   <?php
   session_start();
   $varsession = $_SESSION['usuario'];
   <!--Modal Formulario-->      
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 test" style="overflow-y:scroll">
      <br>
      <center>
         <h2>Pacientes</h2>
      </center>
      <br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-mod1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Registrar    Paciente</button>
      <div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-            labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-  label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <center>
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Registrar    Nuevo Paciente</h4>
                  </center>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                  <form  method="post" class="form-mod" id="agregarpaciente">
                     <br>
                     <div class="area">
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nombre(s)</label>
                           <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control inputs">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Apellido Paterno</label>
                           <input type="text" name="ap_paterno" class="form-control inputs">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Apellido Materno</label>
                           <input type="text" name="ap_materno" class="form-control inputs">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Edad</label>
                           <input type="text" name="edad" class="form-control inputs">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Staff</label>
                           <input type="text" name="staff" class="form-control inputs">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Procedencia</label>
                           <br>
                           <select id="ini4" name="proced">
                              <option value="Externo">Externo</option>
                              <option value="Interno">Interno</option>
                           </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Alergias</label>
                           <br><textarea rows="4" cols="30" class="txt1" name="alergias">
                           </textarea>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-  dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--Buscador-->
      <form class="form4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Busqueda</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control in1" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Ingrese nombre o numero de staff">
         </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btnpac">Buscar</button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btnpac2">Borrar</button>
      </form>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div id="div1"></div>
   </div>

   <script>    
     document.getElementById("agregarpaciente").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post("InsertarPaciente.php", $(this).serialize()).done(function() {
               alert("Success");
            }).fail(function() {
               alert("Error");
            });
        });
   </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Asegúrate que la URL de AJAX es correcta.

Comment: si lo es. Lo extraño es que si utilizo esa misma sintaxis ajax pero poniendo de url el archivo holamundo.php que solo dice hola mundo , si lo ejecuta y muestra el mensaje.

Comment: Ya utilize tu sintaxis @Jota pero aun asi no hace nada. Esto exta muy extraño

Answer (score 0):

Yo pondria el siguiente codigo jQUERY usando AJAX para enviar la data al PHP:

```
//ESPERAMOS QUE DEN CLICK EN EL BOTON SUBMIT #add        
$("#add").click(function() {
    //VALIDAMOS LOS INPUTS LOS QUE SEAN NECESARIOS
    if ($("#exampleInputEmail1").val().length < 1 && $("#exampleInputEmail1").val().length < 1) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("LOS CAMPOS ESTAS VACIOS!");
    } else {
        var data = $("#agregarpaciente").serialize();//SERIALIZAMOS TODO
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'Procesar.php', //ARCHIVO PHP, EL CUAL DEBE ESTAR EN LA MISMA UBICACION
            data : data,
            beforeSend: function(){
                //AGREGAMOS UN SPINNER MIENTRAS PROCESA LA SOLICITUD
                $("#add").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>');
            },
            success: function(response){
                if(response=="Guardado"){
                    $("#add").html('<i class="fas fa-save fa-fw"></i>');
                    alert("GUARDADO CON EXITO!");
                }
                else { return false; }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```